# Goのテンプレート表示について

Tags: html, go

Goでデータベースから取得した情報をテンプレートの出力しようとしましたが、以下のエラーでできません。

エラー
`2015/07/14 21:29:21 http: panic serving [::1]:64252: html/template:base.html: "<" in attribute name: "\n</div>\n"`

ディレクトリ構成は以下のようになっています。

ディレクトリ構成

```html
├── inqueryHandlers.go
├── loger.go
├── main.go
├── models.go
├── proxyHandlers.go
├── router.go
├── routes.go
└── templates
    ├── base.html
    └── inquery
        └── index.html
```

inqueryHandlers.go内で以下のようにテンプレートを表示しようとしたのですができませんでした。

inqueryHandlers.go

```html
    data := map[string]Inqueries{
        "Inqueries": inqueries,
    }
    tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("templates/base.html", "templates/inquery/index.html"))
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")

    err = tmpl.Execute(w, data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

Inquery, Inqueriesの定義は以下のようになっています。

```html
// Inquery is mel.
type Inquery struct {
    Id      int       `json: "id"`
    Content string    `json: "content"`
    Created time.Time `json: "created"`
}

// Inqueries are models.
type Inqueries []Inquery
```

また、base.htmlとindex.htmlはいかのようになっています。

```html
<!--base.html-->
<html lang="ja">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      {{ template "content" . }}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```html
<!--index.html-->
{{ define "content" }}
<h1>お問い合わせ一覧</h1>

{{ range .Inqueries }}
<div>
  <p>{{ .Content }}</p>
  <p>{{ .Created }}</p
</div>
{{end}}
{{end}}
```

どこが間違っているかわかりますか。

ちなみにこちらの記事を参考にさせていただきました。
http://qiita.com/taizo/items/38e4af19e2f42208a00a

Comment: <p>{{ .Created }}</p **←**

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます!!完全に見落としていました。
評価しますので回答お願いします。

Comment: わざわざ私が回答するほどの内容でもないので、ご自分で回答してください。

Comment: わかりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

index.htmlのpタグのとじ括弧が抜けていました。